# "poor quality article" vs "article of poor quality"

Tags: word-usage

> **We will not buy "article of poor quality".**

This sentence is an answer from a test.
I know **"article of poor quality"** is grammatical.
But I could not find its usage when googling. I've only found
**"the poor quality article".**

So I'd like to know whether this usage is natural or not.

Comment: Your example sentence is not idiomatically or syntactically valid English. Take a different test.

Comment: You can use Google to _find_ such tools, but Google itself is not a reliable tool for a student of English. "Google" is just a search engine that indexes millions of websites written by millions of people. In fact, as of today you _can_ find the phrase _"article of poor quality"_ with Google: this very page.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence is not quite correct

> We will not buy *articles* of poor quality.

would be more correct and would be understood to mean "*things of poor quality*".

Usually the actual article would be mentioned

> toys of poor quality
>   clothing of poor quality
>   furniture of poor quality